# The method service.events().list of google-calendar-api returns data beyond the time frame

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I use google-calendar-api to get event data of calendar from this api [link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list?authuser=1).

I want to get event data from `2018-01-02T00:00:00+09:00` to `2018-01-03T00:00:00+09:00`.

So I set `timeMin=2018-01-02T00:00:00+09:00` and `timeMax=2018-01-03T00:00:00+09:00`

You can see it like this:

[image]

But in the response,the event data from `2017-11-21T14:30:00+09:00` to `2017-11-21T15:00:00+09:00` also returned. Why?

You can see a part of the response:

```
{
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3083629687318000\"",
   "id": "XXX",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=XXXX",
   "created": "2018-11-10T01:52:22.000Z",
   "updated": "2018-11-10T01:54:03.659Z",
   "summary": "ForTest",
   "creator": {
    "email": "XXX@XXX.XX.jp",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "XXX@XXX.XX.jp",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-11-21T14:30:00+09:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-11-21T15:00:00+09:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
   },
   "recurrence": [
    "EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:XX",
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=XX;BYDAY=TU"
   ],
   "iCalUID": "XXX@XXX.XX.jp",
   "sequence": 3,
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3083629687318000\"",
   "id": "XXX",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=XXXX",
   "created": "2018-11-10T01:52:22.000Z",
   "updated": "2018-11-10T01:54:03.659Z",
   "summary": "Nice Day",
   "creator": {
    "email": "XXX@XXX.XX.jp",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "XXX@XXX.XX.jp",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-01-02T14:30:00+09:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-01-02T15:00:00+09:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo"
   },
   "recurrence": [
    "EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Tokyo:XX",
    "RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=XX;BYDAY=TU"
   ],
   "iCalUID": "XXX@XXX.XX.jp",
   "sequence": 3,
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
```

I don't think this event from `2017-11-21T14:30:00+09:00` to `2017-11-21T15:00:00+09:00` should be returned. Why did it returned?

Comment: And you are sure the recurring event returned does not have a single instance in the range you requested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event from `2017-11-21T14:30:00+09:00` to `2017-11-21T15:00:00+09:00` is recurrent events.

If I set `singleEvents=True`,the recurrent events will return single events.

Then this problem will be solved.